# android downloaded file miss after process killed

Tags: android, file, process

I have downloaded a jpeg file and written it to SD card, but after process was killed the file is missing. Why?

I write a file like this：

```
fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
int length = 8192;
byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
while (-1 != (length = in.read(buffer))) {
    fileOut.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
fileOut.flush();
fileOut.close();
```

and here is the code exit:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: First, don't call System.exit() on Android.  2nd, what Android version and how are you testing that the file is missing?

Comment: android4.0, search file in adb shell like this: busybox find -name "file name"

Comment: and how to close the app process?

Comment: Don't!  A basic Android principle is that the process stays around for potential re-use, unless the system needs its resources.  You, as a developer, should not ordinarily be trying to close a process.